# Laravel image crop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make an image cropper using Laravel. I have the following working php code to do that, but could anyone please tell me how can I achieve the same using Laravel?

```
$dst_x = 0;
$dst_y = 0;

$top = 15;
$left = 230;
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

$src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('public/upload/' . $filename);

imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $left, $top, $width, $height, $width, $height);

$random_name = rand() . ".jpg";

imagejpeg($dst_image, 'public/upload' . $random_name);
```

Comment: Have a look at this package: http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: Laravel doesn't include an image manipulation component, so this would be done the same as in bare PHP. You can use the Intervention Image component Ross mentioned with or without Laravel, but it fits in really nicely with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no image manipulation implemented directly in the framework. You can do it either using standard PHP that you write in a controller or a helper, or with [this package](http://image.intervention.io/) that is very useful and fully integrated with laravel.